# Replace contents across non-contiguous cells across multiple worksheets - Error 1004

Tags: excel, vba

I am an Excel VBA novice and am hoping for help on a bit of code. We have a workbook with four identical worksheets, one for each quarter of the year. What I would like to do is run code on a command button click that replaces identifying name information with generic, sequentially numbered information (**ex: Joe Smith becomes Male1)**. There are multiple participant types, represented across the worksheet columns and also in multiple rows within the spreadsheet. So, data for males are in cells C11, C28, C45..C215, J11, J28, J45, X11, X28, X45...AE215 across 4 tabs.

I have a Worksheets Array that identifies the four quarterly tabs, and code for each participant type that defines the range of cells where their names would be listed.

The below code is giving me **Error 1004 Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed** at the `For Each MaleCare` line... Any insight into what I am doing wrong?

```
Sub DelConfSAVE()
    Dim sh As Worksheet

    For Each sh In Worksheets(Array("Oct-Dec Attendance", "Jan-Mar Attendance", _
    "Apr-Jun Attendance", "Jul-Sep Attendance"))

        'Replace Male Caregiver (X)
        Dim MaleCare As Range
        Dim X As Integer

        X = 0

        For Each MaleCare In sh.Range("C11, C28, C45, C62, C79, C96, C113, C130, C147, C164, C181, C198, C215, J11, J28, J45, J62, J79, J96, J113, J130,J147, J164, J181, J198, J215, Q11, Q28, Q45, Q62, Q79, Q96, Q113, Q130,  Q147, Q164, Q181, Q198, Q215, X11, X28, X45, X62, X79, X96, X113, X130, X147, X164, X181, X198, X215, AE11, AE28, AE45, AE62, AE79, AE96, AE113, AE130, AE147, AE164, AE181, AE198, AE215")
            If MaleCare.Value <> "" Then
               X = X + 1
               MaleCare.Value = "MaleCare" & X
            End If
        Next MaleCare

        Exit For

        'Replace Female Caregiver (Y)
        Dim FemCare As Range
        Dim Y As Integer

        Y = 0

        For Each FemCare In sh.Range("D11, D28, D45, D62, D79, D96, D113, D130, D147, D164, D181, D198, D215, K11, K28, K45, K62, K79, K96, K113, K130, K147, K164, K181, K198, K215, R11, R28, R45, R62, R79, R96, R113, R130, R147, R164, R181, R198, R215, Y11, Y28, Y45, Y62, Y79, Y96, Y113, Y130, Y147, Y164, Y181, Y198, Y215,AF11, AF28, AF45, AF62, AF79, AF96, AF113, AF130, AF147, AF164, AF181, AF198, AF215")
            If FemCare.Value <> "" Then
                Y = Y + 1
                FemCare.Value = "FemCare" & Y
            End If
        Next FemCare

        Exit For

        'And additional code for Youth1 Youth2 Youth3 OtherAdult cut for posting brevity

    Next sh
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stephanie, Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub DelConfSAVE()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim X As Long, Y As Long, i As Long

    For Each sh In Worksheets(Array("Oct-Dec Attendance", "Jan-Mar Attendance", _
    "Apr-Jun Attendance", "Jul-Sep Attendance"))

        X = 0

        For i = 11 To 215 Step 17
            With sh
                '~~> Male
                If Not Len(Trim(.Range("C" & i).Value)) = 0 _
                Then .Range("C" & i).Value = "MaleCare" & X

                If Not Len(Trim(.Range("J" & i).Value)) = 0 _
                Then .Range("J" & i).Value = "MaleCare" & X

                If Not Len(Trim(.Range("Q" & i).Value)) = 0 _
                Then .Range("Q" & i).Value = "MaleCare" & X

                If Not Len(Trim(.Range("X" & i).Value)) = 0 _
                Then .Range("X" & i).Value = "MaleCare" & X

                If Not Len(Trim(.Range("AE" & i).Value)) = 0 _
                Then .Range("AE" & i).Value = "MaleCare" & X

                '~~> Female
                If Not Len(Trim(.Range("D" & i).Value)) = 0 _
                Then .Range("D" & i).Value = "FemCare" & Y

                If Not Len(Trim(.Range("K" & i).Value)) = 0 _
                Then .Range("K" & i).Value = "FemCare" & Y

                If Not Len(Trim(.Range("R" & i).Value)) = 0 _
                Then .Range("R" & i).Value = "FemCare" & Y

                If Not Len(Trim(.Range("Y" & i).Value)) = 0 _
                Then .Range("Y" & i).Value = "FemCare" & Y

                If Not Len(Trim(.Range("AF" & i).Value)) = 0 _
                Then .Range("AF" & i).Value = "FemCare" & Y

                X = X + 1: Y = Y + 1
            End With
        Next i

        'And additional code for Youth1 Youth2 Youth3 OtherAdult cut for posting brevity
    Next sh
End Sub
```

Comment: Siddharth - this looks like it works perfectly. I will need to add additional code for the remaining types of people and give that a test. Thank you so much for this.

Comment: Woops - hit enter too soon. Can you clarify for me what the "Step 17" part of the code means?

Comment: If you notice that there is a sequence i.e if every cell in a particular column is after 17 cells for example C28 is 17 cells after C11 and so on. I simply put them in a loop :)

Comment: An elegant solution. Thank you so much! My headache has disappeared!

Comment: Kool :) Do consider to accept an answer if your query is solved :)

Comment: Okay, I guess today is not a good problem-solving day for me. How do I "accept" your answer? I have searched around on this site (new here) and don't quite see how to do this. Agh! Sorry!